# Prepping query for incoming data

Tags: powerquery

My problem is as follows.

My dataset:

| Cat1 | Cat2 | Jan | Feb | Mar | Oct | Nov | Dez |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 2020 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 4 | 3 |
| 2020 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021 | 1 | 10 | 8 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

The problem here is that I know that there is data incoming for april, june, july, etc. until october. However, the existing dataset only has these months. I have prepared a pivot table for this from which I extract data with VLOOKUP.

Now the problem is that with the current design I know that when new months are introduced the whole table will shift to the right, therefore ruining the existing VLOOKUP. Is there any way I could add the missing months without causing problems in the future or do you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Is your data really in a pivot table? Then just reference the pivot table using the GETPIVOTDATA formula instead of a vlookup. Then it won't matter how many columns you have, or where.  You can wrap it in an IFERROR formula in case the result is not in the table.

Example pivot and formula for highlighted cell

[image]

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Value",$A$1,"Cat1",2021,"Cat2",1,"Attribute","Jan")
```

Is your data NOT in a pivot table but in a regular table? Then instead of using a direct column number in the vlookup, use a MATCH formula

```
= vlookup ( blah, blahrange, 2, false)
```

becomes

```
= vlookup ( blah, blahrange, MATCH("JAN",A2:I2,0), false)
```